# Optimistic Lock and Spring Data JPA

Tags: spring-data-jpa, optimistic-locking

I am using Spring Data JPA in my project and plan to adopt the Optimistic Locking mechanism. But I have not seen Spring Data JPA can work with Optimistic Lock.

I have a concrete example and as far as I understand it is a situation where Serializable Isolation cannot cover when multiple transactions are being read and updated.

[*The concrete example*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftRem.png)

I'm using the **Cockroach Database**, which only supports **Serializable** Isolation. And here are two functions that I'm used to interacting with the Database:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity(name = "account")
@DynamicUpdate
@ToString
public class AccountEntity {

  @Id
  @Column(columnDefinition = "UUID")
  private UUID id;
  
  @NotNull
  @Column(name = "status")
  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  private Status status;
  
  @Version
  private Long version;
  
}
```

*Account entity*

```
  public AccountDto getAccount(UUID id) {
    AccountEntity entity = this.accountRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow();
    return new AccountDto(entity.getId(), entity.getStatus());
  }
```

*GET API*

```
  @Transactional
  public AccountDto updateAccount(UUID id, @Valid Long sleep,
      @Valid AccountUpdateDto accountUpdateDto) {
    log.info("Start updating status [{}] for the account {}.", accountUpdateDto.getStatus(), id);

    AccountEntity entity = this.accountRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow();

    entity.setStatus(accountUpdateDto.getStatus());
    
    AccountDto accountDto = new AccountDto(id, accountUpdateDto.getStatus());
    log.info("Finish updating status [{}] for the account {}.", 
    accountUpdateDto.getStatus(), id);
    return accountDto;
  }
```

*PUT API*

In the image, I expect to throw an `OptimisticLockException`.
But when **User 1** updates the account, it still can update the account normally. Because in the `updateAccount` method, it was found the latest version of the account. And it can't occur the `OptimisticLockException`.

So under what scenario can it throw an OptimisticLockException?

Answer (score 1):

Optimistic locking takes effect when a transaction starts with seeing version A of some data and later on sees a different version A' of that data.

But as you state Cockroach DB uses the transaction isolation level serializable.
This means for each transaction everything looks like there are no other transactions running at the same time.
Therefore the scenario above can't happen.

Switch to a database with more lenient transaction isolation level and you should be able to see an `OptimisticLockingException`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But because my [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftRem.png), it doesn't have any concurrent transactions, Isolation doesn't work in my case. 
I also tried with Postgres DB, but it still did not work. 
My example is based on this [post](https://vladmihalcea.com/optimistic-locking-version-property-jpa-hibernate/) by Vlad Mihalcea. But I want to apply for Spring Data JPA.